# To refresh JTable JAVA

Tags: java, swing, swing-app-framework

I wanted to refresh JTable immediately when data is inserted or deleted ,i got problem looked at forums but the solutions are too particular to their examples,is there a general way how JTable is refreshed on any event on same page happens? specially when the event changes data upon which the table model relies..

Comment: *"looked at forums but the solutions are too particular to their examples"*  So where's the code that shows *your* best attempt?  Or do you expect us to spoon-feed the answer to you, based on the scant information supplied?

Answer (score 5):

Updates should be done directly to the TableModel. The model will then notify the table so the table can repaint itself.

If you are using a custom TableModel, then it is your responsibility to make sure the proper fireXXX() methods inherited from the AbstractTableModel are invoked when the TableModel is changed.

Using the DefualtTableModel is an easy way to start since it does all this for you.

Comment: usage of DefualtTableModel +1

Comment: I would not go that far and recommend DefaultTableModel as it does not support the nice default renderers by returning something good from getColumClass()